# Git clone creates a sub-folder with a .git folder in it

Tags: git

After creating a "my_project" local folder for my project and executing `git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/my_company/my_project.git` in it, I obtain a "my_project" sub-folder containing its own .git folder (I didn't create myself the project on bitbucket).

So

1. my cloned project is in `my_project/my_project/` instead of just `my_project/`, and
2. there's a .git folder in `my_project/my_project/` that came with the rest.

What did I do wrong and how to get the project in current folder without any existing .git sub folder?

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong, that's the expected behaviour.

Comment: Feels weird to me, thanks though!

Comment: I agree. Go to the parent folder and execute again the git clone command. It will give you the desired result.

Comment: Or simply use `git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/my_company/my_project.git .` (note the trailing dot) from within your existing `my_project` directory to avoid the nested directory being created.

Answer (score 4):

That is expected behavior. Don't create the subfolder you want to clone the repository into. Just clone into your main directory, and it'll create a folder *for* the repository, along with all of the necessary data.

The `.git` folder inside is what **git** uses to keep track of all commits, history, branches, everything!

So you'd do something like

```
cd ~/all_my_projects
git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/my_company/my_project.git
```

Then, you will have a folder that lives at `~/all_my_projects/my_project` which will contain all the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

Git by default makes a new folder called the same as the project.

To over ride this you simply add another argument to the command

Ie

```
Git clone URL test
```

That will place the clone in a folder called test

You can use . to mean the current directory

The last way to "clone" is

```
 Git init
 Git remote add origin (your URL)
 Git fetch
```